My oracle 12c database trace only shows parameter names - how do I see actual parameter values?
I have a database that is already designed. I made a tracer in order to read the queries that I have run from application against the database, the queries are logging to the trace file but there is a problem that it shows only parameter names, e.g. :B6 instead of actual values and I want to find out the queries for each screen of the application it don't help me that much. if there is a better way to find the queries run by any user from application please? or if the tracer can be improved. thanks.
ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = TRUE;
SELECT * FROM V$SESSION WHERE USERNAME = 'myDb';
EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE(session_id => 1338 , serial_num => 8269, waits => TRUE, binds => TRUE);

after finding the trace I used tkprof
tkprof myTraceFile.trc myTraceTxtFile.txt sys=no sort=fchela

which gave me this:
SQL ID: 9m22qp63dh8tp Plan Hash: 0

ALTER SESSION SET REMOTE_DEPENDENCIES_MODE=SIGNATURE


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        2      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      2      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        4      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Parsing user id: 588  
********************************************************************************

SQL ID: 3hvc6qdvdxkf4 Plan Hash: 0

INSERT INTO DOCUMENT (DOC_NO, TAX_TYPE_NO, TAX_PERIOD_NO, TAX_PAYER_NO, 
  DOC_TYPE_NO, CREATED_DATE, LETTER_NO, ASSESS_NO, RECEIVED_DATE, 
  PRINTED_DATE) 
VALUES
 (:B56 , :B55 , :B54 , :B53 , :B52 , :B51 , :B50 , :B49 , :B48 , :B47 , :B46)

I want the real query with its value.

Is there bind information in the raw trace file?  tkprof aggregates data in the trace file so it is combining results in this case for 2 different executions of the same SQL (presumably with different bind variable values).  The raw trace file should have those values, the tkprof summary will not.

If you are using :B56, etc. then your app is parsing the SQL with bind variables and binding values to them, which is the proper way to do it. But then the SQL statement is by definition abstracted from the values specified at each exec. So, you shouldn't expect to see the values in the SQL, as they aren't part of the SQL.
You need to enable a 10046 trace at level 4 or higher (8 or 12) in order to get bind values reported in the .trc file so you can see what they were - but they will be reported in a special listing, not as part of the SQL. You will also need to examine the .trc file yourself, without using tkprof, as tkprof summarizes SQL activity in a way that leaves out details like binds for individual executions.
Examples of how to set a 10046 trace at a specific level:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof
Note that this is primarily intended for DBAs.
